# Which of the following are countable?

Tags: cardinals

Which of the following are countable?

1. The set of all algebraic numbers
2. The set of all strictly increasing infinite sequences of positive integers.
3. The set of all  infinite sequences of  integers which are in arithmetic progression.

**My try**:

1.countable ;since algebraic numbers are roots of equation of a polynomial over $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q$ is countable so the set is countable.

2.cardinality of set of all functions from $\Bbb N\to \Bbb Z^+$ is $\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}=\mathbb c$.So uncountable.

3.Unabe to proceed.

Please check my solutions and how to proceed with $3$

Comment: The title seems fairly irrelevant to the question.

Comment: The argument for 1 is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

For the last point, you fix the starting point, the common difference, and the number of terms. So the number of arithmetic progression has cardinality $\mathbb{N}^3$, which is countable. Others are correct.

Edit: As Noah correctly pointed out below, the OP asks for infinite sequences in arithmetic progression. Here, you just fix the starting point and the common difference, so the number of these ones is still countable. As a shortcut, you cay regard any infinite arithmetic progression as the extension of a finite one, and since the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is the "smallest" infinite, the same conclusion follows.

Comment: I don't get the solution ;I will have to find the number of such sequences whose terms are in A.P. not the number of A.P. s